# How to programmatically add ChildVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have storyboard:
[image: myStoryBoard]

As you can see i have **MenuViewController : UIViewController** with container. Container is
**MenuTableViewController : UITableViewController**
with **MenuTableView : UITableView**.

What I want to do is change size of my Container (MenuTableViewController) and add another Child to my mainVC.

I add it in MenuViewController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MenuTableViewController* secondChildVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuTableViewController"];
    [secondChildVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addChildViewController:secondChildVC];
    NSLog(@"MenuTableViewController.view info: %@",secondChildVC.view);
    NSLog(@"secondChildVC views: %@",[secondChildVC.view subviews]);

    MenuTableViewController *firstChildVC = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [firstChildVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 504)];
    [firstChildVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    NSLog(@"firstChildVC views: %@",[firstChildVC.view subviews]);

}
```

And this is my log:

```
MenuTableViewController.view info: <MenuTableView: 0x8910e00; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x761eca0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x76202b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2013-05-03 17:20:10.796 TestStories[41780:c07] secondChildVC views: (
    "<UIImageView: 0x76205e0; frame = (0 541; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7620680>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x7620740; frame = (313 517; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x76207e0>>"
)
2013-05-03 17:20:10.798 TestStories[41780:c07] firstChildVC views: (
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x7143110; frame = (0 320; 160 320); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x713cc10>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x7140b90; frame = (0 0; 160 320); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7140ce0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x7135000; frame = (0 497; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71351b0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x7135270; frame = (153 517; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7135310>>"
)
```

Why my secondChildVC does not contain TableViewCells? No idea.

You can see that i use red and green colors for background (red for secondChildCV). But probably never appears. Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I've answered the question you asked, but why do you want to add the second child in code? Since you're doing it in viewDidAppear, it's going to show up right away, so why not just make 2 container views in the storyboard in the first place?

Comment: I want to decide how many containers i will have in runtime. So i can't create it in storyboard. This is more likely prototype container rather then final product. Of course if this idea is ..hmmm...not good i'm open to suggestion how make it better :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're doing a couple of things incorrectly. The child view controller will be the same size as the container view, so you should have an IBOutlet to the container view, and change its size, rather than changing the size of the child view controller.

For the second child, you add it as a child, but you never add its view to MenuViewController's view. You also should call didMoveToParentViewController right after you add it as a child. So you need to do something like:

```
    MenuTableViewController* secondChildVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuTableViewController"];
   [secondChildVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [self addChildViewController:secondChildVC];
   [secondChildVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   secondChildVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,160,504);
   [self.view addSubview:secondChildVC.view];
```

Notice also that you can more simply get a reference to the storyboard with self.storyboard

Comment: Thank you! That very helpful. But one more question. I want to do this in runtime, so if i change the size of containerView i can create another right next to firstone?

Comment: @SimpleMan Do you intend to use auto layout, as suggested by your screen snapshots, or are you going to turn that off?

Comment: @SimpleMan, you don't need to create another container view, it's nothing but a normal UIView (from a code standpoint). You could add a subview of any size, and then add the secondChildVC to that, but there's no particular reason to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with rdelmar regarding programmatic custom container calls.

I'd also observe that you're using Auto Layout (iOS 6+ only), so you can't just change the `frame` of views any more. You really should be modifying constraints. Do you need auto layout? If not, turn it off. And you *have* to turn it off if you want to support iOS versions prior to 6.0.

If you stay with autolayout, you should create `IBOutlet` for the appropriate constraint and then use that constraint's constant to change the layout. Incredibly easy to change `UIView` control dimensions that way.

Taking this a step further, programmatically adding a view to an autolayout scene can be a hassle to get all the constraints right. Frankly, I think it's much easier to put *two* containers on the scene (one for each child view) from the get go, but then basically hide one by setting its width to zero. You can set their constraints to effectively be (describing it in VFL) `@"|[container1][container2]|"`, and then set the width of the hidden one to be zero. Then, when you want to show the hidden container, set its width constraint's constant to be whatever you want. When you do that, that will automatically resize both containers.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I'm using autolayout, but i don't think i will need it in my app. The problem here is i can't do it in storyboard becouse i want to decide how many tableview appears in VC at runtime.

Comment: @SimpleMan Understood. Turn off autolayout and your `frame` setting logic should work like you expect. Autolayout will often thwart any attempts to set `frame` properties manually. You can do this in auto layout, but it's just a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Thanks! But out of curiosity.. if I want to stick with autolayout i have to edit constrains from code, right? There is a only way?

Comment: Good catch on the constraints, I didn't notice that. Personally, I always use auto layout and do it just like you recommend with a zero size second container.

Comment: @SimpleMan Two options: 1. Add all of the containers that you'd possibly need, add IBOutlets for their width constraints, and edit those constraints constants in code; 2. Add none of the containers in IB, but do it all in code, and then when you add the containers programmatically, you either use `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES` and then you can use frames, or just build the constraints programmatically (which really isn't too hard). It's just annoying to add view to existing scene that already has fully satisfied set of constraints. Can be done, but a hassle.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a lot of time